# REDIS - how to store comments

Tags: redis

Hi I need your opinion on the design pattern for comments for REDIS:

is it better to store text comments for 1 post as :

```
- a single LIST where I will RPUSH all comments (may be up to 100chr each string)
- a single LIST of commentID (with RPUSH) and a new comment object each time...?
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are your anticipated access patterns?  Read/write heavy?  What scale?

Comment: I have to assume it may have to support up to 100/1000 comments

Comment: I would suggest using SORTED SETS sorted by timestamp(epoch as score). This might help in use cases like retrieving latest comments by time.

Comment: list or sorted sets are the same pattern here - I may end up with a list/set of 1000 comments of 100chrs each. Is it acceptable?

Comment: What kind of read/write rates?  I'm looking for comments per time unit.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with 1000 comments with 100 characters each.  I like John's suggestion of a sorted set.

Keep things simple, but don't paint yourself into a corner on the client side if you later find you have reason to go the other route.

Comment: what about 1000 comments with 1000 characters each? is it still suitable for redis?

Comment: @programmer, I still imagine you'd be OK.  It's really easy to write a shell script (or similar) to populate with some test data to see how it behaves in your environment.  Use the `info` command to get _started_ with understanding capacity of your Redis instance.